# Ubuntu $(dollar) sign kind-of-escaping text. Why? Workarounds?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have written a basic code to tell whether a password is secure in C. It returns 0 or 1 based on whether it is secure or not. When I pass command line arguments in ubuntu it works fine unless the password contains with a $ sign. Therefore I wrote a program to output all the arguments and it went like this:

```
./a.out abc pqr stu $vwx x$yz ab$c
0 -> ./a.out
1 -> abc
2 -> pqr
3 -> stu
4 -> x
5 -> ab
6 -> def$
```

But this works:

```
./a.out  abc pqr stu \$vwx x\$yz ab\$c def\$
0 -> ./a.out
1 -> abc
2 -> pqr
3 -> stu
4 -> $vwx
5 -> x$yz
6 -> ab$c
7 -> def$
```

Why is this happening? and is there any other way to avoid it (so that it works for something like `./a.out $abc` rather than giving a segmentation fault.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dollar-sign is used by *the shell* to expand environment variables, it has nothing to do with your program.

When you use `\$` you escape the dollar character so the shell doesn't use it for variable expansion. You can also put arguments inside single quotes, like e.g.

```
$ ./a.out abc pqr stu '$vwx' 'x$yz' 'ab$c'
```